# Mongoose numChanged argument?

Tags: mongoose, node-mongodb-native

How does mongoose determine the number of documents that were changed in an `.update()`? Does the `node-mongodb-native` driver return that information? I can't seem to find this in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does:

```
db.collection('foo').update({},
    {$set:'foo'},
    {multi: true},
    function (err, numberUpdated) {
      console.log(numberUpdated);
    });
```

If you don't use `multi: true` the numberUpdated will be always 0 or 1.

Documentation and examples for node-mongodb-native [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#update).

How does it works? When the `w` option of the update command (called write concern) is  greater than or equals to 1 (default to 1) the driver executes the [`getLastError` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError), this command returns among other things the [number of records affected by the operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/#getLastError.n).

Example with the mongo repl from another answer in SO:

```
> db.count.update({x : 1}, {$inc : {x : 1}}, false, true)
> db.runCommand({getLastError : 1})
{
"err" : null,
"updatedExisting" : true,
"n" : 5, //this
"ok" : true
}
```